# What is the name of this shower part - that connects a shower head to the ceiling?

Tags: plumbing, shower, pipe, plumbing-fixture

I've got a porcelanosa rain shower head (item #100067715) in my master bathroom, and it is hanging from the ceiling.  The connector piece seems to have sprung a pin-hole leak and is spraying out mist.  Looking on the porcelanosa website, I only see the shower head itself - not the roughly 7" square connector pipe that is actually leaking.  What is the name of that part, and is it the kind of thing that I can pick up at one of the big HW stores?

This is the link to the shower head:

https://www.porcelanosa-usa.com/products/bath/rain-shower-heads.html/nk-logic-square-rain-shower-head-18340.html

and here is the tech specs:
https://pdfgenerator.porcelanosagrupo.com/generar_FTEC_PDF.php?articulos=100067715&lang=ENG&un=1&mercado=USA&output=I&test=1

It indicates that the connector is 1/2"-14NPT.  But the connector's cross section is square (presumably for aesthetics, with a round pipe inside).  What is the name of this kind of pipe?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really sure it would have a specific name besides fancy designer shower tube/pipe.  The fitting size at top and bottom is the most important, the shape is only designer looks.

Comment: That 7" arm is apparently a custom part for Porcelanosa. They show one with a 45 degree bend online. Your best bet is to contact the company directly.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002240931727.html  no doubt worth every cent!

Comment: Do you know what's happening above the ceiling?

Answer (score 1):

"Square shower arm" gets many results in an internet search. Your item does not appear to have any close connection with the actual shower head.

Comment: how is this a answer

Comment: It's a flat square shower head fed from above - see photo.

Comment: *shower [head] arm, straight*, +1. ... It's called *propitiatory*. .... "at one of the big HW stores?" Probably not. That's an Amazon special, obviously of the highest quality given that it leaks.